# CUPS source-code compiling error

Tags: centos, cups, apple, source-code

I want to get printer state from CUPS. To do that , I am trying to customize CUPS's source code. So I can send a message to my front-end.

I have downloaded CUPS repository from gitub [Apple's CUPS repo](https://github.com/apple/cups/archive/master.zip)

Then unzip it and ran

`./configure`

I am getting following error.

> auth.c: In function ‘cups_crypt’: auth.c:2017:5: error: unknown type
>   name ‘_cups_md5_state_t’ _cups_md5_state_t state; /* Primary MD5 state
>   info / ^ auth.c:2018:5: error: unknown type name ‘_cups_md5_state_t’
>   _cups_md5_state_t state2; / Secondary MD5 state info */

If I just use `yum install cups` it works fine.

What went wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can use yum, then get the src version corresponding to what you are running, `yumdownloader  --source cups`